# How to choose between two options with a biased coin

Tags: probability

We would like to choose between theatre and cinema by tossing a coin. Unfortunately the only available coin we have has probapility of heads $p\ \left(\dfrac{1}{2}<p<1\right)$. How could we use that coin to take a good decision so that the two options have equal possibilities?
My solution: we will flip the coin twice, if it comes up heads first and tails second, then we will go to the theatre. If it comes up tails first and heads second, then we will go to the cinema. If the two flips are the same, we flip twice again, and repeat the process until we have a unbiased toss. Is it correct?

---

*Note added by joriki*: As discussed in the comments, I'm reopening the question because of the aspect that the probability $p$ of heads is known and may be used to optimise the algorithm; this aspect was not present in the question [Puzzle about technique of fair using of unfair coin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849430) as a duplicate of which this question had been closed.

Comment: @MartinR: It's not an exact duplicate. Here we know $p$ and can use it to improve on the solution.

Comment: "Your" solution is called von Neumann's procedure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin

Comment: @joriki: Hmm I doubt knowing $p$ helps. There's an optimal solution that extracts the maximum possible number of bits from a biased coin, namely $H(p)$.

Comment: @Did: Neither that duplicate question nor the wikipedia article seem to mention the optimal algorithm (described in http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/coinflipext.pdf).

Comment: @user21820 Believe it or not but the question of the efficiency of the algorithms is one I know something about, and this is not at all what the present post is asking.

Comment: @Did: Yea I was just stating it, since your link didn't mention it, and it would be a shame to leave it untold.

Comment: @Did: But of course the solution is from Von Neumann, anyone knows it! I didnt meant that i invented it!

Comment: So, you are asking if a solution invented by von Neumann and well known for ages, is correct? Not sure I am following, then...

Comment: @user21820: You're talking about the optimal rate for converting a stream of biased flips into a stream of unbiased bits. Here we need a single flip to decide where to go, so we should optimise the expected number of biased flips to generate one unbiased flip, not the rate for an infinite stream. I think that for that problem, knowing $p$ should help.

Comment: @Nick: Please indicate whether you're interested in the efficiency of a solution for generating a single unbiased flip from flips with known bias $p$. If so, I'd reopen this question, since that question isn't addressed in the other thread.

Comment: @joriki: I'm not sure that it's true in general. Of course in special cases like $p = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ then exactly 2 flips will suffice since "HH" will have probability $\frac12$, but if say $p = \frac1{π}$ then can you give a better algorithm than the multi-level strategy?

Comment: @user21820: I haven't calculated the expectation yet, but I will if the OP indicates interest. My tentative belief that knowledge of $p$ should improve the expectation for generating a single flip is based mainly on the fact that it allows us to finish after the first flip with probability $1-p$, which no algorithm for unknown $p$ (including the multi-level strategy) can do.

Comment: @joriki: Ahh I see..

Comment: @joriki yes, please reopen the question.

Comment: @user21820: The improvement from making use of $p$ turns out to be quite substantial; see my answer.

Comment: @joriki: I don't want to check the details of your post but I certainly believe you that it makes a big difference in the manner of arithmetic coding. =)

Answer (score 4):

As already discussed in comments, your algorithm is correct and doesn't require knowledge of $p$. There is [an improved algorithm](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/coinflipext.pdf), mentioned in a comment by user21820, that also doesn't require knowledge of $p$ and is optimal in the sense that it converts a stream of biased flips into a stream of unbiased flips at the maximal rate determined by the entropy of the biased distribution.

However, as you only want to go to the theatre or the cinema once (by the way: why not go to a movie theatre?), you're probably not interested in the long-term conversion rate of an infinite stream but in the expected number of flips required to make this one-off decision.

In the algorithm you propose, you essentially perform trials consisting of two flips each, with a success probability of $2p(1-p)$. Thus the expected number of flips is

$$
2\cdot\frac1{2p(1-p)}=\frac1{p(1-p)}\;,
$$

which is anywhere from $4$ for $p=\frac12$ to arbitrarily large numbers for $p\to1$.

The notes on the improved algorithm linked to above derive the expected time it requires to produce a bit. (The analysis is carried out for an algorithm that's not quite as sophisticated as the one that achieves the optimal flip rate, but the two algorithms coincide until the first unbiased flip is produced.) The result is

$$
2\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+p^{2^k}+(1-p)^{2^k}\right)\;.
$$

This is a bit of an improvement, with values ranging from about $3.4$ for $p=\frac12$ to arbitrarily large numbers for $p\to1$.

But there's actually a simpler approach that does considerably better, in the spirit of [arithmetic coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding). Let's generalise the problem to using the biased coin with heads probability $p$ to simulate another possibly biased coin with heads probability $q$. We can then apply this with $q=\frac12$ to simulate a fair coin.

The basic idea is that for all $p$ and $q$ there is always one result $A$ of the real coin that is at most as probable as one result $B$ of the simulated coin, so we can stop with result $B$ when $A$ occurs and continue with a suitable new value of $q$ if it doesn't. The result can be defined recursively (with $0$ representing tails, $1$ representing heads, $X(q)$ a simulated result with heads probability $q$ and $Y(p)$ an actual result with heads probability $p$:

$$
X(q)=\begin{cases}
0&q\lt p\land Y(p)=0\;,\\
1&q\ge p\land Y(p)=1\;,\\
X\left(\frac qp\right)&q\lt p\land Y(p)=1\;,\\
1-X\left(\frac{1-q}{1-p}\right)&q\ge p\land Y(p)=0\;.
\end{cases}
$$

for $q\ge\frac12$, and $X(q)=1-X(1-q)$ otherwise. (This is to be read more like pseudocode for a recursive program than a mathematical definition, as the variables $X$ and $Y$ stand for different quantities in each iteration.)

I haven't been able to figure out the expected number of throws to produce the first unbiased flip with this algorithm, but here are the results of simulations (in red), graphed together with your simple algorithm (in purple), the more elaborate algorithm linked to above (in green) and the lower bound $-\log2/(p\log p+(1-p)\log(1-p))$ from entropy (in blue):

[image: comparison of expected numbers of throws]

The improvement is substantial; you need roughly half as many throws on average. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/e69f15fd3ea0148c7c8e01fc1404bb11) for the simulations.

Comment: Your graph is puzzling. Why, when $p=0.5$ precisely, do you not perform exactly one coin toss?

Comment: @MartinKochanski: You could certainly do that as an exception to the general algorithm for that one value of $p$; but note that the question specifies $p\gt\frac12$, and for $p\to\frac12^+$ we need $2$ tosses on average: One in case the first toss is tails (yielding the immediate result tails), and one plus on average two more if the first toss is heads, since we then have to keep going until the next heads, which takes an average of two tosses.

Comment: There is certainly a discontinuity at $p=\frac12$. I **thought** that was the only reason but it seemed best to check.